# Python 3 Inheritance Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance, super

I am a Python novice and I am having difficulty with inheritance and using 
super()

The code below is giving me this error

> Exception has occurred: AttributeError
> 'ObjB' object has no attribute 'job'

But I'm not sure why as job is an attribute of ObjB

The test code is this..

```
class ObjA():
    def __init__(self, astr):
        self.name = astr
        self.decorate()

    def decorate(self):
        self.name = '['+self.name+']'

class ObjB(ObjA):
    def __init__(self, aname, ajob):
        super().__init__(aname)
        self.job = ajob

    def decorate(self):
        super().decorate()
        self.name = self.name + ' is a ' + self.job

test = ObjA('Fred')
print(test.name)

test2 = ObjB('Fred', 'Baker')
print(test2.name)
```

What I was expecting was this

```
[Fred]
[Fred] is a Baker
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `ObjB.__init__()` method you are calling `super().__init__(aname)` before you set `self.job = ajob`, so that when the `decorate` methods are called, the `self.job` is not yet set. Try moving the `self.job = ajob` earlier in the `__init__()` method, like:

```
class ObjB(ObjA):
    def __init__(self, aname, ajob):
        self.job = ajob
        super().__init__(aname)
```

Another way to fix the problem is to eliminate the `decorate()` methods completely:

```
class ObjA():
    def __init__(self, astr):
        self.name = '['+astr+']'


class ObjB(ObjA):
    def __init__(self, aname, ajob):
        super().__init__(aname)
        self.job = ajob
        self.name = self.name + ' is a ' + self.job
```

Comment: Yes, this does correct the problem, but it is caused by the fact that I was not expecting the `__init__` on ObjA to call the `decorate` method on ObjB. Can this be avoided?

Comment: I have edited my answer above to include another possibility that eliminates the `decorate()` methods completely.

Answer (score 0):

The key thing is that when you use `super` in subclass to call `__init__` in base class, the `self` passed to `__init__` **is the instance of subclass `ObjB`** rather than `ObjA`. Therefore, the `self.decorate()` in `ObjA`'s `__init__` calls actually the `decorate` method in `ObjB`, that's why the `job` is not defined.

`super().__init__` functions like this: `ObjA.__init__(test2)`

Below comes from [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance) about inheritance

> Derived classes may override methods of their base classes. Because methods have no special privileges when calling other methods of the same object, a method of a base class that calls another method defined in the same base class may end up calling a method of a derived class that overrides it.

Comment: Ok. When creating ObjB, what I want is the decorate method of ObjA to be called by ObjA's `__init__` and the decorate method of ObjB to be called by ObjB's __init__ is there a way to achieve this or do i need to restructure my class to not call the decorate method from the `__init__`?

Comment: @CHaste One way is using `ObjA.decorate(self)` in your `__init__` method but this is a bad practice. I think you need a clear design of structure. If `ObjA` is meant to inherited and methods are to be overwritten, then be careful to call methods in `ObjA` because it may be overwritten by subclasses.